# How to create an std::function as method argument with std::stoi as default value?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, std

I would like to use an `std::function` as an argument of a method and set its default value as `std::stoi`.

I tried the following code:

```
void test(std::function<int(const std::string& str, size_t *pos , int base)> inFunc=std::stoi)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
no viable conversion from '<overloaded function type>' to 'std::function<int (const std::string &, size_t *, int)>'
```

I managed to compile by adding creating a dedicated method.

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>


int my_stoi(const std::string& s)
{
    return std::stoi(s);
}

void test(std::function<int(const std::string&)> inFunc=my_stoi);
```

What's wrong in the first version?
Isn't it possible to use `std::stoi` as default value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What's wrong in the first version?

There are two overloads of `stoi`, for `string` and `wstring`. Unfortunately, there's no convenient way to differentiate between them when taking a pointer to the function.

> Isn't it possible to use std::stoi as default value?

You could cast to the type of the overload you want:

```
void test(std::function<int(const std::string&)> inFunc =
    static_cast<int(*)(const std::string&,size_t*,int)>(std::stoi));
```

or you could wrap it in a lambda, which is similar to what you did but doesn't introduce an unwanted function name:

```
void test(std::function<int(const std::string&)> inFunc =
    [](const std::string& s){return std::stoi(s);});
```

Comment: Why doesn't it complain on `typedf int (*fn)(const std::string&,size_t*,int); fn f = std::stoi;`?

Comment: @CharlesPehlivanian: Because only one overload is convertible to that function type (which is why the cast in my example works). Either could be an argument to the template constructor of `std::function`, and the compiler isn't allowed to instantiate both template specialisations to see which one might be valid.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: thanks for the explanation, I was thinking that there was something like this but could not figure out what.